Fiber product of schemes and tensor calculations
In Vakil's notes, starting from 10.2.A, he listed a few tensor identities to help calculating fiber products of schemes, for example (supposing $B\to A$ a ring map, giving $A$ the structure of a $B$-algebra):

Adding an extra variable: $A \otimes_B B[t] \cong A[t]$,
Base change by closed embeddings: $A/I^e \cong A \otimes_B (B/I)$,
Base change of affine schemes by localization $S^{-1}A\cong A\otimes_B S^{-1}B$.

With these basic tools we're able to compute various tensor products (hence fiber product of schemes), and I'm trying to apply this to an example made up by myself. Consider the projections of $\Bbb A^2=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]$ to the diagonal line $Z=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(x-y)$ from the horizontal and vertical directions, namely:

How do we calculate the fiber product? Topologically the result is a $3$-dimensional thing, it is the subset of the direct product of $\Bbb A^2\times \Bbb A^2$ as
\begin{align*}
\Bbb A^2\times_Z \Bbb A^2 &= \{(p, q)\in \Bbb A^2\times \Bbb A^2\mid \pi_1(p)=\pi_2(q)\}\\
&= \{(x, y, z, w)\in \Bbb A^2\times \Bbb A^2\mid y=z\}\\
&\cong\operatorname{Spec} k[x, y, z, w]/(y-z).
\end{align*}
My question is, how do I use the above basic tools to calculate the tensor product and get the same result? Namely how do I show the following identity (if it is correct) step by step?
\begin{align*}
k[x,y]\otimes_{\frac{k[x,y]}{(x-y)}} k[x, y] \cong \frac{k[x, y, z, w]}{(y-z)}.
\end{align*}

First apply some changes of variables. We are tensoring over $k[x,y]/(x-y)\cong k[t]$. Next, we have $k[x,y]=k[x,t]$, using $t=x-y$. Thus we can write the tensor product as $k[x,t]\otimes_{k[t]}k[t,z]$, which equals $k[x,t,z]$.
